# I can't properly connect 2 monitors on my kubuntu setup with a NVIDIA NVS 310 GPU

Tags: kubuntu, gpu

I tried to connect 2 monitors to my setup, but I can't configure them as 2 independent monitors. They always show the same screen.

It might be that my GPU is not powerful enough, but I am not sure.

I run Kubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Is the proprietary nvidia binary driver installed or are you using nuveau?

Comment: Are you sure that in **Settings>Devices>Displays** you chose '*Join Displays*'? And are you sure that you installed the appropriate Nvidia driver?

Comment: @singrium to be honest I'm not even capable of finding the appropriate setting in Kubuntu, KDE is just too much of a mess lol

Comment: @sevku you can check [KDE documentations](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/systemsettings/using-kapp.html).

Comment: @sevku that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7Gb48XQUXQ) may help you too.

Comment: @singrium, I have found the display settings, but there's no option for joining displays. I've had multi monitor setups on kde before, but it never behaved like this.

Comment: Then it may be a drivers problems, are you sure you have the latest proprietary driver for Nvidia?